# Zero width spaces creating problems with Redirects?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, seo

I've implemented a lot of 301 redirects using the [Wordpress Redirects plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), the problem is that it's flagging up a lot of 404 pages where redirects actually exist.

Upon closer inspection, it looks like this problem has been caused by 'Zero-width spaces' (`&#8203;`) in the URLs generating 404 errors.

e.g. the redirect has been created for:

`/page/item/1`

And the following item is throwing a 404 error:

`/&#8203;page/&#8203;item/1`

It's confusing because outside of markup mode they look identical:

/page/item/1

/​page​/​item​/1

(but if you copy the first one and do a find all, it won't match the second!)

In any case, I'd quite like to create a mod_rewrite rule (or something similar) that simply takes URLs with zero width white space characters, and removes them. This would ensure redirect rules are correctly picked up.

I appreciate in some cases this will lead to a redirect leading to a redirect, but this is preferable to unecessary 404 errors.

Is this possible using mod_rewrite or other functionality in Apache?

Comment: Where did you find the 'zero width spaces' as webmaster tools generates guff like that and if you found it there then that is not an issue on your site.

Comment: You're better off finding out how these characters are making it into URLs to begin with, then stopping it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the characters are making it into the URLs as some external pages are linking to them with the spaces ... unfortunately that's completely out of our control.

Comment: @user29671 These are logged in the Wordpress Redirect plugin, I'm pretty sure it's accurate.